# Entity framework - ProviderIncompatibleException only first time I run my program

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a really wierd error in my program I am using entity framework (code first) , every time when I run my program and access my DbContext the first time I get ProviderIncompatibleException , **but** if I exit the program and run it again everything is working fine. The full exception is:

```
 System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection)
       at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at IEX.ManagementServer.Monitor.IMSMonitor.MonitoringManager.Start() in C:\Develop\IEX\trunk\IEX.ManagementServer\IEX.ManagementServer.Monitor\IMSMonitor\MonitoringManager.cs:line 209
       at IEX.ManagementServer.WebServices.Host.Mediator.Initialize(Boolean dropAlways) in C:\Develop\IEX\trunk\IEX.ManagementServer\IEX.ManagementServer.WebServices.Host\Mediator.cs:line 49
       at IEX.ManagementServer.WebServices.Host.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Develop\IEX\trunk\IEX.ManagementServer\IEX.ManagementServer.WebServices.Host\Program.cs:line 51
  InnerException: System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException
       HResult=-2146233087
       Message=The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.
       Source=EntityFramework
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
            at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection)
       InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
            HResult=-2146232060
            Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
            Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
            ErrorCode=-2146232060
            Class=20
            LineNumber=0
            Number=-1
            Server=""
            State=0
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
                 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
                 at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
                 at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
                 at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
                 at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
                 at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
                 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
            InnerException:
```

Someone help please?

Comment: What do you mean first time? You start program, close it, and start again? And when error occurred again?

Comment: When I start it the first time... Start -> error occured , Stop , Start -> everything is fine...

Comment: The error of interest is: HResult=-2146232060
            Message=A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread. But, by any chance, are you trying to change the `app.config` file during runtime?

it happened to me, and @Evk gave me a [great explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32612264/1188208) of what was happening.