# ProviderIncompatibleException when running first time. But, not in second time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, connection-string

So, basically I'm using `EF` with `Reverse POCO Code First Generator` in my project.

My connection Strings look like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="HistoryDBContext" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ProjectMgtContext" connectionString="data source=xxx;initial catalog=xxx;user id=xx;password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The idea is that I am going to read the `connectionString` for `HistoryDBContext` from `ProjectMgtContext` (which is working fine) and then rewrite the `connectionString` from `HistoryDBContext` using:

```
public static void WriteConnectionString(string connectionString)
{
    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    var connectionStringsSection = (ConnectionStringsSection) config.GetSection("connectionStrings");

    connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings["HistoryDBContext"].ConnectionString = connectionString;

    config.Save();

    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
}
```

However, this only works the `second time` that I run my project because during the first run, it complains that the `connectionString` is empty:

[image]

So, obviously my approach is not working. How should I approach this?

Thank you

**Edit**

More code:

```
while (ProjectManager.HaveProjects())
{
    var project = ProjectManager.GetNextProject();

    if (project == null) continue;

    /*Write the current project to the configuration file*/
    Connection.WriteConnectionString(project.ConnectionString);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do you call your WriteConnectionString before doing anything related to entity framework? Maybe EF just reads it before you refresh?

Comment: Yeah. That's what I thought. I'm doing everything before. I don't know what to do :/

Comment: Your WriteConnectionString method is fine, so problem is in another part of code. Try do that the first line in your program's Main method.

Comment: I posted some code. As you can see, I loop through all the rows from `ProjectMgtContext` and then I write the `connectionString` to continue the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well most likely it won't work this way. EF might not re-read your connection string from configuration every time it needs it. It might as well cache either whole configuration or just connection string in memory. App.config is for connection strings that are not changing often during application runtime (or better at all). Just pass connection string to your ProjectMgtContext directly, or do like this:

```
public partial class ProjectMgtContext : DbContext {
    public static string DefaultConnectionString;
    public TestEntities()
        : base(DefaultConnectionString)
    {
 }
```

And then update DefaultConnectionString static property. If you generate your context from template - edit template to add default connection string as above.

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of this. I'll use the constructor